# Java can't combine two functions

Tags: java

I have an assignment to do. And I have it done, but I made it in 2 functions. Automatic checker that we use does not work when i have multiple functions in my class.

NB! How to merge these 2 functions ??

```
package stamps;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class Stamps {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> findstamps(int sum, int[] stamps){

            ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int index = 0; index<stamps.length; index++){
                    test.add(stamps[index]);
            }
            ArrayList<Integer> pusto = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> vastused_one = new     ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

            vastused_one.addAll(findstamps2(sum, test, pusto));

            int min = 99999999;
            ArrayList<Integer> vast = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (ArrayList<Integer> list : vastused_one){
                    if (list.size()< min){
                            min = list.size();
                            vast = list;
                    }
            }

            System.out.println("Here it is : " + vast);
            return vast;
    }

public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> findstamps2(int sum, ArrayList<Integer> stamps, ArrayList<Integer> mem) {

            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> vastused = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

            for (int i : stamps ) {
            ArrayList<Integer> my_mem = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            my_mem.addAll(mem);
            System.out.println(my_mem + " " + mem);
            if (sum - i == 0){
                    my_mem.add(i);
                    vastused.add(my_mem);
                    System.out.println("Found " + my_mem);
                    System.out.println("ADDED : " + vastused);
                    break;
            }
            else if (sum - i < 0){
                            my_mem.add(i);
                            System.out.println("Terminated " + my_mem);
                    }
            else {
                    my_mem.add(i);
                    vastused.addAll(findstamps2(sum-i, stamps, my_mem));
                    }
    }
            System.out.println("RETURNING : " + vastused);
            return vastused;

}


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Call both and take one result? Call both and concatenate the results? Call both and throw an exception if the results don't match?...

Comment: Move the code from findstamps2 into findstamps... can't understand the problem... you like a codereview? if you do unfortunately this is not the correct place... check out the code review site..

Comment: If you know how to write them both separately, then surely you know how to write them both as a single function?

Comment: I can not change the function signature that is used in first function. Thus I dont know how to use signature from the first function and run the program recursively so that I could save done steps in memory(3'th variable in function 2).

Comment: I need to make a method that uses the first sigranture (public class Stamps {
    
    public ArrayList<Integer> findstamps(int sum, int[] stamps) {
          // TODO
    }

}) but behaves as these 2 methods behave together.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the same function recursively with the same signature you will have to come up with an iterative approach instead. I don't want to give too much away since this is obviously a homework assignment, but what you have there should be possible with a while or do while loop.

Comment: @FiedbergNichenko Your question is nonsensical. `while` loops terminate based on _any_ condition you choose. But in fact your `for` loop in `findstamps2` should work just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. I only have your code above to go from and no real context. However if you set your exit condition on the while loop appropriately then you shouldn't need to know the numbers of anything

Comment: I dont see a way to solve this problem using only while loops.

Comment: Task: Function is given a int[] of values and a finish value. I need to find the shortest combination of those int values that will in SUM give me the given finish value. And I can use one value from the list multiple times.

Comment: ok, you can definitely do that with just iteration. I would suggest that you start from scratch with an iterative approach and see how you get on. If you have a specific problem with your solution then post a new question. Sorry, I know it's not ideal but I think it's your best option at the moment.